# Setting a canvas element with JavaScript as the background?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set this "matrix effect" to be the background of my html5 website, but whenever I attempt to but elements "above" the canvas the elements fade out with the text of the canvas. This same text also renders above the image.

I tried making a separate canvas to put the image on but it just moves the image.
I have also tried several variants of this "matrix effect" but they all do the same method of fading out the letters.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('background_canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const katakana = 'アァカサタナハマヤャラワガザダバパイィキシチニヒミリヰギジヂビピウゥクスツヌフムユュルグズブヅプエェケセテネヘメレヱゲゼデベペオォコソトノホモヨョロヲゴゾドボポヴッン';
const latin = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const nums = '0123456789';

const alphabet = katakana + latin + nums;

const fontSize = 16;
const columns = canvas.width / fontSize;

const rainDrops = [];

for (let x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
  rainDrops[x] = 1;
}

const draw = () => {
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.fillStyle = '#0F0';
  context.font = fontSize + 'px monospace';

  for (let i = 0; i < rainDrops.length; i++) {
    const text = alphabet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length));
    context.fillText(text, i * fontSize, rainDrops[i] * fontSize);

    if (rainDrops[i] * fontSize > canvas.height && Math.random() > 0.975) {
      rainDrops[i] = 0;
    }
    rainDrops[i]++;
  }
};

setInterval(draw, 30);
```

```css
html {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body .canvas #background_canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

body #foreground {
  background-color: transparent;
  fill-opacity: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <script src="assets/js/background.js" type="module"></script>
  <canvas id="background_canvas" style='position:absolute; left:0; top:0;'>Cannot Render Canvas</canvas>
</div>
<div id="foreground">
  <script src="assets/js/app.js" type="module"></script>
  <canvas id="foreground_canvas"></canvas>
  <img src="assets/images/pfp.png" alt="My Profile Picture">
</div>
```

Comment: Should make an [edit] to include the relevant code in the question as questions shouldn't rely on external sources to be answered.

Comment: Alright fixed that, thanks!

Comment: _"but whenever I try to put elements above the canvas it fades out and the text is rendered above the canvas"_ - you say you _wanted_ to put elements "above the canvas", and then you complain that it _does_ get rendered "above the canvas" - huh? Please clarify what the actual issue is supposed to be here.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the confusion, i'm trying to put an image "above" the canvas but it fades out with the text of the canvas, the text which also for whatever reason renders above the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `z-index` on `#foreground` to have it displayed on top of `#background`. You will also need to set `position` on it for `z-index` to have any effect:

```css
body #foreground {
  /* existing properties... */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Full working example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('background_canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const katakana = 'アァカサタナハマヤャラワガザダバパイィキシチニヒミリヰギジヂビピウゥクスツヌフムユュルグズブヅプエェケセテネヘメレヱゲゼデベペオォコソトノホモヨョロヲゴゾドボポヴッン';
const latin = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const nums = '0123456789';

const alphabet = katakana + latin + nums;

const fontSize = 16;
const columns = canvas.width / fontSize;

const rainDrops = [];

for (let x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
  rainDrops[x] = 1;
}

const draw = () => {
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.fillStyle = '#0F0';
  context.font = fontSize + 'px monospace';

  for (let i = 0; i < rainDrops.length; i++) {
    const text = alphabet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length));
    context.fillText(text, i * fontSize, rainDrops[i] * fontSize);

    if (rainDrops[i] * fontSize > canvas.height && Math.random() > 0.975) {
      rainDrops[i] = 0;
    }
    rainDrops[i]++;
  }
};

setInterval(draw, 30);
```

```css
html {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body .canvas #background_canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

body #foreground {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  fill-opacity: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <script src="assets/js/background.js" type="module"></script>
  <canvas id="background_canvas" style='position:absolute; left:0; top:0;'>Cannot Render Canvas</canvas>
</div>
<div id="foreground">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/120/120" alt="My Profile Picture">
</div>
```